# How do I shift my table to the end of the section?

Tags: tables, formatting

I made a table for a subsection but when I script it, it doesnt show where it should (it shows in the middle and I want the table at the end of the subsection). The script goes like this:

```
\section{Resolucion}
\subsection{Ejercicio 1}
\paragraph{Para el aire:}
\paragraph{Para aproximar el efecto de la temperatura sobre la viscosidad contamos con los siguientes modelos experimentales:}
\subparagraph{Ley de la potencia $\frac{\mu }{\mu _{0}} \approx\left(\frac{T}{T_{0}}\right)^{n}$}
\subparagraph{Ley de Sutherland $\frac{\mu }{\mu _{0}} \approx \left(\frac{T}{T_{0}}\right)^{3/2}\left(\frac{T_{0} +S}{T+S}\right)$}
\paragraph{Sabemos que la viscosidad del aire a $P_{O}=1 atm$ y 20°C es $\mu_{0}=1,74E^{-5}$ y ademas los valores de las respectivas constantes son $n\approx0,7$ y $S\approx110,4K$. Iterando consecutivamente en cada modelo para las distintas temperaturas obtenemos que:}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
$T_{i}$ {[}ºC{]} & Potencia $\mu_{i}$ {[}kg/m.s{]} & Sutherland $\mu_{i}$ {[}kg/m.s{]} & Experimental $\mu_{i}$ {[}kg/m.s{]} \\ \hline
20               & $1,8244E^{-5}$                  & $1,8386E^{-5}$                    & $1,8E^{-5}$                         \\ \hline
40               & $1,9068E^{-5}$                  & $1,9339E^{-5}$                    & $1,9E^{-5}$                         \\ \hline
60               & $1,9876E^{-5}$                  & $2,0264E^{-5}$                    & $2,0E^{-5}$                         \\ \hline
80               & $2,0668E^{-5}$                  & $2,1161E^{-5}$                    & $2,05E^{-5}$                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try adding the placement option `begin{table}[!h]`.

Comment: `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` are section headings like `\section` the argument should be the _title_ not the whole text of the section.

Comment: @Bernard hi! i tried using !h but it didnt move it all the way to the end of the subsection, any variants to that modification that may push it? thanks btw

Comment: Not mentioned in the answer, but worth remembering: It is (almost) always a good idea to leave a blank line before entering the code for a float.  It's much easier to control that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the `float` and `tabularx` packages. Notice how the commands `\paragraph{}` or `\subparagraph{}` cause all of the text to become bold. This is because they generate a header for a paragraph, and may be unnecessary. The text is generated in paragraphs without headers by omission of these commands. I included one header for a paragraph called "Name" as an example for the use of the `\paragraph{}` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{document}
\section{Resolucion}
\subsection{Ejercicio 1}
\paragraph{Para el aire:}
Para aproximar el efecto de la temperatura sobre la viscosidad contamos con los siguientes modelos experimentales:
\subparagraph{Ley de la potencia}
 $\frac{\mu }{\mu _{0}} \approx\left(\frac{T}{T_{0}}\right)^{n}$
\subparagraph{Ley de Sutherland}
 $\frac{\mu }{\mu _{0}} \approx \left(\frac{T}{T_{0}}\right)^{3/2}\left(\frac{T_{0} +S}{T+S}\right)$
\paragraph{Name}
Sabemos que la viscosidad del aire a $P_{O}=1 atm$ y 20°C es $\mu_{0}=1,74E^{-5}$ y ademas los valores de las respectivas constantes son $n\approx0,7$ y $S\approx110,4K$. Iterando consecutivamente en cada modelo para las distintas temperaturas obtenemos que:

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
$T_{i}$ {[}ºC{]} & Potencia $\mu_{i}$ {[}kg/m.s{]} & Sutherland $\mu_{i}$ {[}kg/m.s{]} & Experimental $\mu_{i}$ {[}kg/m.s{]} \\ \hline
20               & $1,8244E^{-5}$                  & $1,8386E^{-5}$                    & $1,8E^{-5}$                         \\ \hline
40               & $1,9068E^{-5}$                  & $1,9339E^{-5}$                    & $1,9E^{-5}$                         \\ \hline
60               & $1,9876E^{-5}$                  & $2,0264E^{-5}$                    & $2,0E^{-5}$                         \\ \hline
80               & $2,0668E^{-5}$                  & $2,1161E^{-5}$                    & $2,05E^{-5}$                        \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]